# How to align window buttons vertically in Ubuntu as below?

Tags: 20.04, window-buttons

As you can see the the minimize close buttons are aligned vertically and they are transparent.

[image]

Comment: I think it's the Floppy setup --> https://github.com/manilarome/the-glorious-dotfiles

Comment: ...it's part of the awesomeWM but you need to configure it by yourself, as far as I know.

Comment: take note the window title bar is on the left side of the window not across the top which is the normal location ... this might help you search for approaches

Comment: @starkus Can you provide some resources? I am struggling to figure out how to align the window buttons vertically.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. i guess you'll have to search the internet.